# What are all the benefits of a Secondary class for your Primary Class?

Tags: runes-of-magic

Besides the obvious such as a few extra skills, what are all the benefits of having a Secondary Class?

Answer (score 1):

You have no other benefits than the extra skills, except of the fact, that you can swap between them. Maybe if you are bored of being a healer, swap to a DD or a TANK...

Comment: I saw somewhere, that your secondary provides 10% stats or skills or something. Could you help me find this or maybe shed some light on it.